# What is the best way to connect to a remote database server that can only be accessed from a different ec2 instance?

Tags: database-connection, ssh-tunnel

How would I go about connecting to a database that can only be accessed through an ssh tunnel to an ec2 instance. The current route would be:

My ubuntu laptop -> ec2 instance -> postgres database server

- I have complete control over the ec2 instance.
- I only have access to port 5432 of the remote database server via the ec2 instance. It lives on a different server.

I have been accessing the database using the terminal but would prefer to be lazy and use something like pgAdmin or RazorSQL. I am assuming I can do an ssh tunnel to my ec2 instance, then some sort of port forward to the database server but I haven’t been able to get beyond the ssh tunnel.

A double hop ssh tunnel will not work because I don’t have ssh access to the DB server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this - where ec2-dbserver is your database server (inside EC2), and ec2-host is the host that you can ssh2.

You should then be able to point pgadmin-III to localhost:5432

```
ssh -L 5432:ec2-dbserver:5432 user@ec2-host
```

Comment: The DB server is on a separate instance that belongs to someone else. I do not own the database server.

Comment: So?  Your question indicates that you can access port 5432 of the database server from your EC2 instance.  The SSH command accepts connections on port 5432 of localhost, routes them over the tunnel and to port 5432 of the database server. If your ec2 instance can connect to the db server, then you can use this command.

Comment: You're awesome! I'm always missing mundane details. I didn't notice the important difference between your command string and the one I've been using. Thanks!